# Change filename of multiple files at once in linux using single command

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I have multiple files and want to add a character at the beginning of filename, add extension, and remove a word in the center of the filename at once using single command and I run this using bash.
Here are my files:

```
DATA_20210301_INPUT_CHECK 
DATA_20210302_INPUT_CHECK
DATA_20210303_INPUT_CHECK
DATA_20210304_INPUT_CHECK
```

And want to rename them (in one operation) to :

```
1_DATA_20210301_CHECK.DAT
1_DATA_20210302_CHECK.DAT
1_DATA_20210303_CHECK.DAT
1_DATA_20210304_CHECK.DAT
```

How to change all the files name at once with single command? From what I do right know is do all this loop one by one

```
 for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.DAT"; done
 for i in *; do mv "$i" 1_"$i"; done
 for i in *; do mv "${i}" "${i//\_INPUT/}"; done
```

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: ... so `do mv "$f" "1_${f/_INPUT/}.DAT";` ?

Comment: Wah thats work perfectly, thats what I want thank you! @steeldriver

Answer (score 0):

The `rename` command can do that. I know of two versions: GNU and Perl Regular Expressions.

GNU:

`rename DATA 1_DATA DATA*`

Regular expression:

`rename s/^/1_/ DATA*`

Run `rename --help` to find out which version you have.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually two commands but it gives the output that you want:

```
rename 'DATA' '1_DATA' DATA_2021030*_INPUT_CHECK && rename 'CHECK' 'CHECK.DAT' *DATA_2021030*_INPUT_CHECK
```

Output:

```
1_DATA_20210301_INPUT_CHECK.DAT
1_DATA_20210302_INPUT_CHECK.DAT
1_DATA_20210303_INPUT_CHECK.DAT
1_DATA_20210304_INPUT_CHECK.DAT
```